# Can loop yield same outcome as manual looping? Example

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have made a script that compares the current bars high-low to previous 7 bars, whenever its considered the lowest value / range will be colored. Tried to to the same but in a loop function, to ease the process in case one use way more bars. But I cant seem to make it work, is there something wrong in the code  or should it be done manually? Example below.

```
//VARIABLE
bar = high-low

//MANUAL PROCESS WHICH WORKS
bar_count_manual = (bar < bar[1]) and (bar < bar[2]) and (bar < bar[3]) and (bar < bar[4]) and (bar < bar[5]) and (bar < bar[6])

barcolor(bar_count_manual ? color.yellow : na)

//LOOP PROCESS WHICH DOES NOT WORK
bar_count_loop = 0
for i = 0 to 6
    bar[i] < bar[1]
    bar_count := bar_count + 1

barcolor(bar_count_loop == 6 ? color.yellow : na)
```

Answer (score 0):

`bar_count_loop` variable is not used in your example and remains 0 during the runtime. Create a conditional `if` statement and increment `bar_count_loop` value with `+=` operator.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
bar = high-low
bar_count_loop = 0
for i = 0 to 6
    if bar < nz(bar[i])
        bar_count_loop += 1

barcolor(bar_count_loop == 6 ? color.yellow : na)
```